# Деплой Symfony3 при помощи ftp

Tags: symfony2, ftp, развертывание, symfony3

Случилось так, что заказчик проекта оплатил хостинг без поддержки ssh и единственный путь обновить файлы на сервере - это использовать ftp. Если до этого, работая с symfony я мог выполнить команду git pull и получить все файлы на сервер в prod режиме спустя несколько минут, то теперь мне нужно каждый раз при обновлении файлов (а их 100к) ждать около часа.
Очень хочется спросить совета у тех, кто использует ftp при деплое symfony, как можно автоматизировать этот процесс? В смысле не качать каждый раз ненужные файлы, разграничивать prod  и dev окружение и т.д.
И второй вопрос: как собственно symfony понимает в каком окружении она находится? Раньше при помощи ssh это настраивалось автоматически, а теперь если скачивать все файлы через ftp нужно где-нибудь указать окружение?

Comment: Вообще заказчик, конечно, Скрудж макдак... сэкономил на ssh интересно сколько? Предложите ему нормальный облачный хостинг, рублей в 500 за месяц с SSD легко можно найти. 

А вообще по теме вопроса, напишите себе админскую тулзу, которая будет через веб интерфейс делать нужные вам вещи: 1. выкачивать git 2. переключать ветки и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как symfony понимает в каком окружении она находится?

Окружение передается явно в качестве первого аргумента при создании экземпляра приложения. Гляньте на код фронт контроллеров (обычно это файлы `app.php` и `app_dev.php`, лежащие в папке `web`):

```
// web/app.php
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);

// web/app_dev.php
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
```

При использовании консольных команд окружение может быть передано с помощью опции `--env` (значение по-умолчанию `dev`):

```
$ php bin/console command_name --env=test
```

или переменных среды:

```
export SYMFONY_ENV=prod
```

Переменная, чье имя начинается с `SYMFONY__`. будет добавлена в качестве параметра контейнера, а именем параметра будет название переменной окружения после ряда трансформаций:

- префикс `SYMFONY__` будет удален,
- оставшаяся часть имени приведена к нижнему регистру,
- пары подчеркиваний `__` заменены символом точки `.`

Apache, Nginx и другие веб сервера также могут устанавливать переменные окружения. Подробнее в [документации](http://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/external_parameters.html)

> Если скачивать все файлы через ftp нужно где-нибудь указать окружение?

Нет. Более того, деплоить стоит только файлы относящиеся к нужному окружению. Например файлам 'web/app_dev.php, web/config.php, app/config/*_dev.yml, *_test.yml' не место в прод окружении. Так же имеет смысл исключить dev зависимости и оптимизировать автозагрузку:

```
composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader
```

> ... нужно каждый раз при обновлении файлов (а их 100к) ждать около часа

Убедитесь что вы не передаете по сети "лишнего": упомянутые ранее dev зависимости, тесты, папки .git, svn и прочие артефакты VCS как самого приложения так и сторонних модулей, разнообразные файлы кешей, логов, документация - все это не нужно в проде.
Если зависимости приложения обновляются не часто, то и их постоянно "таскать за собой" нет смысла.

А еще можете глянуть на [lftp](http://lftp.tech/) или [ncftp](http://www.ncftp.com/)

Comment: перевод документации http://symfony.com.ua/doc/current/configuration/external_parameters.html